# 'Bare Infinitive' or 'to infinitive'?

Tags: infinitives

I happened to come across a sentence in a school textbook as follows:

> " All you need to do is **keep** that passion burning in you and never give up."

Why is the bare infinitive form "keep" used here?
Can't we use "to keep" instead?

Comment: You certainly can. In cases like this where the infinitival is predicative complement, and the subject NP contains _do_ in a relative clause, "to" can optionally be added.

Comment: 1: *All you need do is wait.* 2: *All you need **to** do is wait.* 3: *All you need **to** do is **to** wait.* They're all fine, though #1 is a bit "distilled, clipped" and #3 is a bit "wordy". But I couldn't endorse 4: *All you need do is **to** wait.*

Comment: *All you need to do is [**you need** [**to**]] keep that passion burning.*

Answer (score 1):

You could certianly write:

> All you need to do is to keep that passion burning in you>

But the form without "to" before the verb is far more common in my experience, and will sound more natural.

> All you need to do is keep that passion burning in you.

In general sentences of the form

> All you need to do is {verb} {object}.

will use a bare infinitive for {verb}.

> - All you need to do is run the perfect mile
> - All you need to do is go to the store.
> - All you need to do is let me know.
> - All you need to do is use the web site.
> - All you need to do is learn the procedure.
> - All you need to do is breath deeply.

Al the above are standard and common. "To" could be added before the verb on any of them, but it is not needed on any, and the form with "to" is now significantly less common. Using "to" would not change the meaning in any way.

Note that in the last case the verb has no object, but the form is stil valid.

**Edit**

A comment, but not the original question, asks about omitting the "to" in the "to do" part of tjhe sentences. This would give such forms as:

> - All you need do is run the perfect mile.
> - All you need do is to run the perfect mile.

Both forms are grammatical. I think the forms with "to do" are more natural, but I am honestly not sure about relative frequency of use here. Perhaps this should be a separ5ate question.

Comment: In all your example sentences, including the sentence in question, **is** is the verb, and the infinitive form whether 'bare' or 'to infinitive' cannot act as the verb. So the part comes after *is* (a copula) is a complement, not object, isn't it?

Comment: Also, see the comment above by BillJ.

Comment: @mahmudkoya have you understoof what BillJ said above in his comment? He is right. FumbleFinger too gave another explanation using ellipsis though I would not prefer that explanation. But if you are comfortable with that explanation it is fine. Because FF is completely correct in his explanation.

Comment: @Man_From_India, what would you say about David Siegel's answer?

Comment: @mahmudkoya He basically said the same thing. I am not the native speaker, so can't comment on whether adding or removing subordinator *to* makes it more natural or less. And similarly I have not done any research on my end to comment of the statistics he mentioned. Surely he did, or if he is a native speaker he can say based on his intuition. But one thing he missed to add, and which that I think is very important is that *to* is optional in predicate when the relative clause in the subject has *do*. That is all I can say about the answer.

Comment: @man_from _India  I did not mention any "statistics" I referred to "my experience". I am a native speaker of English, for what that is worth. I the answer says right at the start that both the form without "to" before the infinitive and the form with "to" are acceptable. The question did not ask about a form with the "to" omitted from "to do", so I did not address that.Now i will.

Comment: @DavidSiegel well sorry. Yes you indeed didn't mention any statistics. But did mention what is more common. I tried to refer to that. I didn't find and was really ignorant about my choice of words :)

Comment: @Man_From_India  I have updated my answer. But this really should be a separate question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers did not use **an** ellipsis, nor refer to elision in his or her comment, Man_from_India.

Comment: @DavidSiegel well in the third comment.

Comment: @Man_From_India  the 3rd comment (2nd by FF) indicates using brackets that certain words are optional, but does not indicate that they have been elided, that is left out. When words are formally required by grammer, but may be omitted because they are implied, that is elision. But sometimes words aree optional, not required. That is not elision. An "ellipsis" is the mark with three dots (...) that indicates that something has been omitted. "ellipsis" can also mean elision.

Comment: @DavidSiegel well I didn't know this. Call it whatever, but we are referring to the same thing :)

Comment: @Man_From_India  omission of **optional** elements is quite different from the elision of formally **required** elements, although in both cases an element is absent.